# How can I write tweets in real time to external resources?

Tags: python, twitter

I just started programming and nobody can rely on it. I didn't really know what was happening and how to fix it.

I want to retrieve text data tweeted in real time using Twitter's API and store it in both a file called test.txt and a redis server.

#### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweet_get.py", line 30, in <module>
    stream.sample()
  File "/Users/macuser/Workspaces/jxpress/trendword/.direnv/python-3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 449, in sample
    self._start(is_async)
  File "/Users/macuser/Workspaces/jxpress/trendword/.direnv/python-3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 389, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/Users/macuser/Workspaces/jxpress/trendword/.direnv/python-3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 320, in _run
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/macuser/Workspaces/jxpress/trendword/.direnv/python-3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/macuser/Workspaces/jxpress/trendword/.direnv/python-3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 289, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "/Users/macuser/Workspaces/jxpress/trendword/.direnv/python-3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 351, in _read_loop
    self._data(next_status_obj)
  File "/Users/macuser/Workspaces/jxpress/trendword/.direnv/python-3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 323, in _data
    if self.listener.on_data(data) is False:
  File "/Users/macuser/Workspaces/jxpress/trendword/.direnv/python-3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 54, in on_data
    if self.on_status(status) is False:
  File "tweet_get.py", line 22, in on_status
    if status.lang == 'ja':
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lang'
```

#### Code

```py
import os
import tweepy
import redis
import math
from collections import Counter

r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

TWITTER_CLIENT_ID = os.environ['TWITTER_CLIENT_ID']
TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ['TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET']

TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = os.environ['TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN']
TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = os.environ['TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET']

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(TWITTER_CLIENT_ID,TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN,TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        status = []
        file = open('test.txt', 'w')
        if status.lang == 'ja':
            file.write(status)
            file.close()

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        return False

stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=StreamListener())
stream.sample()
```

#### Additional information

iOS 10.12.6, Python 3.7.3, Atom

Comment: `status` is an empty list. A list has no `lang` property.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
```
def on_status(self, status):
text = str(status)
file = open('test.txt', 'w')
if status.lang == 'ja':
　file.write(text)
　file.close()
```
After that, I tried to rewrite the code a little, the text file is not generated. Do you understand why?

Comment: The problem remains the same: `status` has no `lang` property. What is `lang` anyway?